# need help looping let runOurCode

Tags: javascript

im trying to set runOurCode true then false every 5 seconds i have tryed setInterval,setTimout,forLoop and still dint worked asked some friends but everyone is offline rn :/

```
var editingCode;
let runOurCode = false
const oldFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
WebSocket.prototype.send = new Proxy(WebSocket.prototype.send, {
  apply: function(target, scope, args) {
    if (typeof(args[0]) === 'string') {
      let json = JSON.parse(args[0]);
      if (json[0] === 3) {
        editingCode = (json[1])
      }
    }
    let data = target.apply(scope, args);
    return data;
  }
})

WebSocket.prototype.send = new Proxy(WebSocket.prototype.send, {
  apply: function(target, scope, args) {
    if (typeof(args[0]) === 'string') {
      let json = JSON.parse(args[0]);
      if (runOurCode) {
        target.apply(scope, [`[5,77]`]) // u dont need function here (MY BAD)
        runOurCode = false // set back to false so it doesnt keep drinking
      }
    }

    let run = false
    document.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
      if (e.code === "KeyC") {
        runOurCode = true
      }
    })

    let data = target.apply(scope, args);
    return data;
  }
})
```

Comment: This didn't work? `setInterval(() => runOurCode = !runOurCode, 5000)`

Comment: forgot abt it but ye it did thank you

Comment: You said you tried `setInterval` and it didn't work.

Comment: i tryed using it like this setInterval(doSomething, 9000);

Comment: That should work if `doSomething` includes `runOurCode = !runOurCode`